# If (no else)-sentences with substring in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, substring

I have a df, I would like to substring the first letters for all columns in the screen_name column, except for the cell with the name 'frank'. All my attempts are ignored by R (substring is executed on all cells). Why?

```
df <- data.frame("screen_name" = c("august", "berit", "christopher", "david", "erica", "frank"), "rt_name" = c("berit", "august", "david", "erica", "frank", "christopher"))

#IF-sentence with '%!like%' 
'%!like%' <- function(x,y)!('%like%'(x,y))
df$screen_name<- if(df$screen_name %!like% ('frank')) {substr(df$screen_name, 1, 2)}

#IF-sentence with !=
df$screen_name<- if(df$screen_name != 'frank') {substr(df$screen_name, 1, 2)}
```

I am looking for solution that include %!like% or similar as the names in the df can vary and I am not always having an exact match.

My expected output is

```
df_exp <- data.frame("screen_name" = c("au", "be", "ch", "da", "er", "frank"), "rt_name" = c("berit", "august", "david", "erica", "frank", "christopher"))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens to `frank`?  Does it remain as-is, or what output do you expect for `frank`?

Comment: I have added expected output (but can see below that you figured it out :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using `ifelse` combined with `grepl` to check if input screen name happen to be `frank`:

```
df$screen_name <- ifelse(!grepl("^frank$", df$screen_name),
                         substr(df$screen_name, 1, 2), df$screen_name)
df

  screen_name     rt_name
1          au       berit
2          be      august
3          ch       david
4          da       erica
5          er       frank
6       frank christopher
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(screen_name = c("august", "berit", "christopher", "david",
                                 "erica", "frank"),
                 rt_name = c("berit", "august", "david", "erica", "frank",
                             "christopher"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```